# I'm adding buttons to my app to allow me to navigate between the activities that I'm working on but one doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

The problem is with the val navToListView in LoginActivity.kt. whenever this button is used the app just crashes. I think the issue may be to do with either activity_list_view.xml or top_bar_menu.xml
Thanks in advance

**Login Activity:**

```
package com.example.mastersproject.ui.login
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.mastersproject.ForgottenPassword
import com.example.mastersproject.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding

import com.example.mastersproject.R
import com.example.mastersproject.ResetPassword
import com.example.mastersproject.SignUp

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val username = binding.username
        val password = binding.password
        val login = binding.login
        val loading = binding.loading

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, LoginViewModelFactory())
            .get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        loginViewModel.loginFormState.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
            val loginState = it ?: return@Observer

            // disable login button unless both username / password is valid
            login.isEnabled = loginState.isDataValid

            if (loginState.usernameError != null) {
                username.error = getString(loginState.usernameError)
            }
            if (loginState.passwordError != null) {
                password.error = getString(loginState.passwordError)
            }
        })

        loginViewModel.loginResult.observe(this@LoginActivity, Observer {
            val loginResult = it ?: return@Observer

            loading.visibility = View.GONE
            if (loginResult.error != null) {
                showLoginFailed(loginResult.error)
            }
            if (loginResult.success != null) {
                updateUiWithUser(loginResult.success)
            }
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)

            //Complete and destroy login activity once successful
            finish()
        })

        username.afterTextChanged {
            loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(
                username.text.toString(),
                password.text.toString()
            )
        }

        password.apply {
            afterTextChanged {
                loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(
                    username.text.toString(),
                    password.text.toString()
                )
            }

            setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
                when (actionId) {
                    EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ->
                        loginViewModel.login(
                            username.text.toString(),
                            password.text.toString()
                        )
                }
                false
            }

            login.setOnClickListener {
                loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                loginViewModel.login(username.text.toString(), password.text.toString())
            }
        }


        val navigateButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigateToSignUp)
        navigateButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, SignUp::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val forgottenPasswordButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.forgot_password)
        forgottenPasswordButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, ForgottenPassword::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        val resetButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.resetpasswordtest)
        resetButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, ResetPassword::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        //This is just a navigation button to use before you add in the login code
        val navToListView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigateToListView)
        navToListView.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, ListView::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }

    private fun updateUiWithUser(model: LoggedInUserView) {
        val welcome = getString(R.string.welcome)
        val displayName = model.displayName
        // TODO : initiate successful logged in experience
        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "$welcome $displayName",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
    }

    private fun showLoginFailed(@StringRes errorString: Int) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

/**
 * Extension function to simplify setting an afterTextChanged action to EditText components.
 */
fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    })
}
```

**activity login xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="272dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sign_in_up_border"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sign_in_up_border"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTint="#1DB954"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:background="@drawable/forgot_password_background"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.468" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/navigateToSignUp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go to sign up"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/navigateToListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="go to list view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetpasswordtest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="go to reset password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**List View**

```
package com.example.mastersproject

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class ListView : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view)

        /* Set click listeners for each ImageView (button)
        profileButton.setOnClickListener { navigateToProfilePage() }
        homeButton.setOnClickListener { navigateToHomePage() }
        settingsButton.setOnClickListener { navigateToSettingsPage() }
    }

    private fun navigateToProfilePage() {
        // Replace ProfileActivity with the actual activity you want to navigate to
        val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun navigateToHomePage() {
        // Replace HomeActivity with the actual activity you want to navigate to
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun navigateToSettingsPage() {
        // Replace SettingsActivity with the actual activity you want to navigate to
        val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

         */
    }

}
```

**activity list view xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListView">

    <!-- Include the top_bar_menu layout -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/top_bar_menu"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="424dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**top_bar_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1DB954"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileButton"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_face_6_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_24" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

tried use button to navigate between pages but app crashes

Comment: It is difficult to figure out what going wrong by just looking at the code. Can you include the stack trace as well? It will probably have the line number where the app is crashing.

Comment: where is the initialization of the button **profileButton** inside the activity **ListView** ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code, you didn't add the initialization of the buttons in the activity **ListView**.

Here's how it should be:

```
class ListView : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view)

    // Set click listeners for each ImageView (button)

    val profileButton = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.profileButton)
    profileButton.setOnClickListener { navigateToProfilePage() }

    val homeButton = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeButton)
    homeButton.setOnClickListener { navigateToHomePage() }

    val settingsButton = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.settingsButton)
    settingsButton.setOnClickListener { navigateToSettingsPage() }
}
private fun navigateToProfilePage() {
    // Replace ProfileActivity with the actual activity you want to navigate to
    val intent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun navigateToHomePage() {
    // Replace HomeActivity with the actual activity you want to navigate to
    val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

private fun navigateToSettingsPage() {
    // Replace SettingsActivity with the actual activity you want to navigate to
    val intent = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

But I would recommend that you learn [databinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) and implement it in your projects.